# CSS Gradient Image Size?

Tags: css, image, gradient

I know that the best way to make a gradient image is to have its width set as 1 and just let it repeat, but I'm confused as to what the height should be?

Should it be really big in case the viewer is on a huge monitor or TV screen or something? Is there a way to have it be just like 1x10 and look normal?

Also, doing rounded corners and stuff like that without using CSS3... using an image - is that possible in a fluid layout?

Heres a gradient thing I'm talking about. [this](http://www.teamliquid.net/mirror/layout/NavbarNormal.png) is the background gradient used on [Teamliquid.net](http://teamliquid.net). It's height is only 33px, yet you can't tell that its repeating on the y axis...?

Comment: Anyway, "really big" here means 256 pixels. The de facto colour standard is 256 values per channel, so if you make a gradient image that is more than 256 pixels high, some of the pixels will be duplicated. 256 is enough, you can't get a finer granularity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of the gradient is 33px, because the navbar has a height of 33px.
When you have a vertical gradient, that means you need to repeat it horizontally and that means you need a width of 1px and a height of the gradient height you want to have.

Comment: WOW. I'm dumb. I was thinking fluid layouts had adjusted heights too. oops

Answer (score 0):

I would just recommend using CSS3 for this effect. There are some great generators. I do some web design and all I use is CSS gradients. Also, if you use an image, it is one more http request the server must handle.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

**EDIT:**
Here's what I do for rounded corners as well.

http://www.cssportal.com/css3-rounded-corner/

They work great for fluid layouts.

Comment: that is the reason why the image files are small. And when one more request to the server for a small image makes a difference in your performance, then you have bigger problems at another place. CSS3 gradients are very cool and I like them. The only problem is the cross browser implementation

Comment: This is true, and it really helps to know your target audience. Most modern browsers support it, and for those that do not they will simply get a solid color. I don't believe it's a bad trade off. Nice to hear other peoples opinions on the subject though.

Comment: No the trade off is not big and I personally use css3 very extensive with fallback techniques for older browsers. But when I look at the experience level of the author of the question, I better keep the possible solution as easy as possible.